# How to redirect to same route after login with React

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am creating a webapp and I would like to have it so that once the user signs in, the page redirects to a new component but the route stays the same. For example, I use Letterboxd.com. When not signed in, letterboxd.com shows a large banner. When you sign in, it redirects to a newsfeed type layout but the route letterboxd.com stays the same. How do I achieve this with rails router? Right now I have a page redirect when the user signs in but it goes to a new route and url.

Comment: There are a lot of ways to do it. I think asking a question must contain demo of your code. So that answer can be specific.

Comment: @moshfiqrony True, I selected a best answer which works for me in my instance. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make sure that, `isLoggedIn` contains some boolean (or similar) type.

```
<BrowserRouter>
    {/* ... Some other Routes */}
    <Route path="/" component={isLoggedIn ? <NewsFeed/> : <Login />} />
    {/* ... Some other Routes */}
</BrowserRouter>
```